# Are the skew-normal distribution and the skew-Cauchy distribution heavy-tailed?

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness, heavy-tailed, fat-tails, skew-normal-distribution

I think the title is self-explanatory. I understand that the skewness and the tail behavior of some distribution are completely unrelated as any symmetric distribution will have a skewness of zero irrespective of how heavy its tails are.

However, I was wondering (i) if the [skew-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) and the [skew-Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution#Skewed_Cauchy_distribution) are heavy-tailed.

(ii) Also, we can get skewed distribution using a selection procedure. That is, if $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian (or Cauchy), $\frac{d}{dz}P(X-kY\leq z|Y>0)$ represents a density of a skewed version of normal (or Cauchy distribution). What about the tails of such constructed skewed distributions?

Note: I say the distribution of a random variable $X$ heavy-tailed if $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{tx} P(X>x) = \infty$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Which definition of heavy-tailed are you using?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I only know one definition of heavy-tailed distributions. That is,
the distribution of a random variable $X$ is said to be heavy-tailed if $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{tx} P(X>x) = \infty$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: That's fine, though some people mean other things when they say "heavy tailed". Could you edit that into your question, please?

Comment: Are you using [this skew Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution#Skewed_Cauchy_distribution) and [this skew normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am using the mentioned skew normal and skew Cauchy.

Comment: Please update your question with the proper definitions to make it self-contained and precise.

Comment: A skew-normal has higher kurtosis than a normal distribution, if that helps

Comment: Thanks, @David, can you cite the article from where you got this information?

Comment: @Joy What makes you think I got that from an article?

Comment: Okay, @David, then can you please justify the statement? I did not get the point.

Comment: R package "sn" allows for skew-normal distribution sample simulation. I checked with it

Comment: Wikipedia shows the kurtosis. Since it is positive, the skew-normal is heavier-tailed than the normal distribution in the sense of leverage of the tails.  See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521769/graphic-representation-of-kurtosis-and-skewness/3532888#3532888

Answer (score 4):

I'll take it that you're happy to take it as a given that the ordinary (symmetric) normal is light tailed and the ordinary (symmetric) Cauchy is heavy tailed.

That the indicated skew-normal is not heavy-tailed is easy to see. I'll discuss the 'standard case' of the skew-normal; the scale-location case is not really any more work.

Taking $f(x)=2\phi (x)\Phi (\alpha x)$, we can immediately see that $f(x)<2\phi(x)$, so 
 $P(X>x)<2(1-\Phi(x))$. Indeed, we can see that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{tx} P(X>x)$ is less than twice that of a standard normal (which we already know to be light tailed, so we know that integral is finite even before we try to evaluate it).

I was somewhat surprised that you selected the linked skew-Cauchy (there are a number of others), because it's associated with a *different* skew-normal (which can be found within the article I linked to).

A somewhat similar approach to the one I used for the skew-normal can be used. Let's restrict consideration to the right half (i.e. consider only $x>\mu$). Then the density is proportional to the density of a Cauchy (because of the parameter $\lambda$), so $P(X>x)$ is proportional to that for a Cauchy. Consequently, the limit goes to infinity because the corresponding quantity for the Cauchy does.

So (without actually having to evaluate it in either case) that particular skew-normal is light tailed and that particular skew-Cauchy is heavy tailed.